# react redux with axios api calls

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I am trying to learn the react and for that I am trying to create a sample todo app. I have a python flask backend which servers as REST server and react as web server.

Everything works find an I am able to show todos and delete particular todo as well. However now I have started learning Redux, and that seems really confusing.

I am not sure how to make call to my rest server. Following just returns promise, not sure how to get the data, rather than promise.

**store.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { createStore } from 'redux'

export const ADD_TODO = 'ADD_TODO'

let nextTodoId = 0
export const addTodo = text => ({
  type: 'ADD_TODO',
  id: nextTodoId++,
  text
})

export const listTodo = todos => ({
  type: 'LIST_TODO',
  todos
})

const add_todo = (id, text) => {
  return axios.post("http://localhost:5001/todos", {id:id, data:text})
    .then(Response=>{
           store.dispatch(addTodo(Response.data));
    })
}

const fetch_data = () => {
  return axios.get("http://localhost:5001/todos")
        .then(Response=>{
          store.dispatch(listTodo(Response.data))
        })
}
const initialState ={
    todos: {},
    new_todo: ''
}

function todoApp(state = initialState, action) {
    console.log("reducer called...")
    switch (action.type) {
       case ADD_TODO:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
          new_todo: action.text
        })
      default:
        return state
    }
}

const store = createStore(todoApp)
export default store
```

**app.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react' 
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
class App extends Component{
 render(){
  return(        
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.addTodo('testing')}>fetch_Data</button>
      </div>

   );
 }
}

export default connect() (App)
```

**index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}> <App /> </Provider>, 
                document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should export the actions you have created which will then be imported and used in the components using the connect HOC.

You can dispatch the 'fetch_data' action to get the data in your component. Also, you can dispatch 'addTodo' action to add new todo in the list.

```
export const ADD_TODO = 'ADD_TODO';
export const GET_TODO = 'GET_TODO';

export const fetch_data = () => {
return (dispatch) => axios.get("http://localhost:5001/todos")
    .then(response => {
         dispatch({type: GET_TODO, todos: response.data});
    })
}

export const addTodo = text => ({
  type: 'ADD_TODO',
  id: nextTodoId++,
  text: text
});
```

Use the actions constants like ADD_TODO, GET_TODO to save or to update the redux state in reducers

```
const todoApp = (state = initialState, action) => {
console.log("reducer called...")
switch (action.type) {
   case ADD_TODO:
      const todos = {...state.todos};
      todos[action.id] = action.text;
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        todos: todos
      });
   case GET_TODO:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        todos: action.todos
      });
   default:
      return state
   }
}
```

Importing the actions and then call the function you have added in the 'mapDispatchToProps' to dispatch the actions.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { addTodo, fetch_data } from "../store";
class App extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.props.addTodo(todoId, 'testing')}>fetch_Data</button>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    todos: state.todoApp.todos
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    addTodo: (id, text) => dispatch(addTodo(id, text)),
    fetch_data: () => dispatch(fetch_data())
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Answer (score 0):

redux is based on actions and reducers, basically reducers are pure functions which means no side effects as for example api calls, I'd advice you read more about redux and how to use redux with redux-chunk for making api calls

Answer (score 0):

You make this work like this. You need to dispatch action when you have response.

```
const fetch_data = () => {
  return axios.get("http://localhost:5001/todos")
    .then(Response=>{
           store.dispatch(addTodo(Response.data));
    })
}

export const addTodo = text => ({
  type: 'ADD_TODO',
  id: nextTodoId++,
  text: text
})
```

Comment: does that mean rather than dispatching action, I call this function? How should I use this in my JSX (insider provider) ?

Comment: call addTodo('eating') will new toDo. every things remains same. addTodo function is still used to add to do'S.

Comment: I am getting an error `TypeError: this.props.addTodo is not a function`